# How to count elements that have been loaded to the page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a repeating region on a page that is loaded / edited / deleted / added to via jquery (.ajax and .load methods)

There must be a minimum of 3 of these 'regions' before the form can be submitted, so I need to count the number of DIVs with a certain class.

Because the number of DIVs changes via AJAX, I can't count them using something like:

```
        var numItems = $('.anobjective').length;
```

(I'm guessing because they aren't in the DOM).

I can use the above as part of the .load or .ajax function (eg: on **success:** ), which seems to work, however as there are so many different things going on that can change the number of DIVs, is there a global way of counting how many occurrences there are in the current document from within the validation function?

Thank you.

Comment: provide HTML , jquery , ajax code you tried

Answer (score 0):

Initialize at the beginning items collection [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('anobjective');
```

Then at any arbitrary moment you can get actual items number with

```
console.log(items.length);
```

This works due to usage of [live NodeList collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection). It's going to be updated automatically and always reflect actual state of things no matter what happens on the page.

This solution is IE9+.

Comment: Thanks dfsq.  I tried this, and it sort of worked... the validate() function I wrote gets called on document.ready (to show/hide some stuff depending on a few factors). The console.log reports that there are 0 objectives (there are 4 on the test document).  However, the validation function also runs when an 'accept' tick box is clicked, and this time it correctly counts 4.